# Удалить скрипт из страницы полностью, в т.ч. из памяти

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем привет! Есть такая ситуация: одна главная страница, к ней через ajax добавляется еще страница, и происходит конфликт некоторых скриптов. Можно ли при подгрузке второй страницы удалять выборочные скрипты из главной страницы причем так, чтобы они не оставались в памяти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать замыкания

```
(function(){
"use strict";
//код скрипта
}());
```

Тогда количество конфликтов сведется к минимуму.

Comment: Нет не помогло((

Comment: В чем заключается конфликт?

Comment: На подгружаемой странице есть java скрипты и они с галереей и они перестают работать. А как только я удаляю один скрипт с главной страницы то все работает.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть. Может у того скрипта есть функция аля отменить действие плагина(destroy, stop) или это не плагин, а просто скрипт?

Comment: @DOsS: Вы не описали, в чём заключается конфликт. Вы описали _видимые_ последствия конфликта. Выясните, в чём состоит конфликт на уровне кода, например, какие переменные у скриптов общие.